# Geometry Nodes Not Appearing When Added to Object - No Group Attributes

Tags: geometry-nodes

## Edit

I've redone the tutorial for the third time and the problem has persisted. However, I think the issue is the "No group output attributes connected" error that shows up below the Geometry Nodes modifier. When trying to apply weight paint to the object surface (The "Icing") there is no option to alter the density to that of the weight paint, I assume because there is no assigned group. How do I solve this issue? So far I've tried: recreating the sprinkle, setting the sprinkle's origin to geometry, and assigning the sprinkle to the icing by list and by dragging the object from the menu into the geometry node work area.

While I'm still not sure why this issue is occurring, by redoing the tutorial from the start and then by setting the cylinder's origin I now have more than one sprinkle! I just turned my density up to 800,000 for now, until I can figure out why this is happening.

I followed the advice of the answer and have redone this part of the tutorial, which has improved my results! So thank you very much! But I'm still encountering the same problem, just with marginal success. I now have a handful of sprinkles if I turn my density up to 50000, but it isn't nearly what I need.
[image]

## Original Question

I'm following the Blender Guru donut tutorial for 3.0 and I 'm having issues on Part 9 - Geometry Nodes.
And the first issue begins when I attempt to add the Distribute Points On Faces node to my geometry nodes.
[image]

In the tutorial, adding the Distribute Points on Faces node causes large, sharp geometry nodes to appear on the object. My object disappears when I add this node.
I decided to keep going in the tutorial, although I think this is the root of the problem. The next step in the tutorial is to add the Join Geometry node, which I do and this brings my object back into view.
[image]

After that the tutorial had us model the object that was going to become instances on the base object. We did this by adding the Instances on Points node and then dragging the object that will become the nodes (in my case a cylinder named "Sprinkle") into the Geometry Nodes work area, so we can use its shape.
[image]
[image]

Then I was supposed to get the geometry of the "Sprinkle" to be the node on the base object, but even when I linked these nodes it didn't appear.
[image]
I upped the Density to 100 and the seed count from -50 to 300, but nothing appeared. So I looked for a solution and found that I should apply the scale of my node object (the "Sprinkle") to get it to appear. I tried this next.
[image]

However, as you can see, nothing happened. But I figured out that I can cause one sprinkle to show up if I put the Density between 300-800 and the Seed Count to 1. Anything outside these parameters and it either doesn't react or the single "Sprinkle" vanishes.
[image]

What went wrong and why? I'm very new to Geometry Nodes.

Comment: you have several objects here marked as "not visible" in viewport: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yRqM.png so just click on the eyes and put them on. if problem is solved, great. if not, pls provide blend file

Comment: It seems to me that all your objects are created in a microscopic scale. Can you please check the N panel to see what the dimensions of the donut are?

Answer (score 2):

If you watch a tutorial and do not get same results as what's shown in it, it is best to just start again from the beginning and follow the instructions more thoroughly. This is kind of standard solution that solves pretty much all problems with something not working same as in a tutorial.

It is worth noting that geometry nodes are actively developed at the moment so you should also make sure the tutorial is for the exact same version of Blender as you are using so you have the same functionality as the tutor.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful answer to this question. I am sure it is the solution to 20% of the *Geometry Nodes* questions asked here, which is why it should be permanently pinned to the top of the list!

Answer (score 1):

This kept happening to me, I checked the error in the geo node modifier and it said no group output attributes connected. Then i realized it made the group input and output already for me and i just needed to zoom out super far to see it was below my view.

Answer (score -1):

I am also a novice at blender and was facing the similar issue.
There was a comment in the same tutorial which might solve the issue you are facing (it solved mine).
Make sure the Sprinkle's origin is set to its center.
(Right click original sprinkle>set origin>origin to geometry)

I hope that solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I just did that and nothing changed, but it is a good tip to keep in mind in the future when I make new meshes.